# Sorting multiple vectors with "slices" distributed across many files

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, optimization, multidimensional-array

I'm dealing with a big data problem:  I've got some large number of arrays `(~1M)` that are distributed across a large number of files `(~1k)`.  The data is organized so that the `i`th file contains the `i`th entry of all arrays.  If the overall cost of my algorithm is determined by the number of files that I need to open (and assuming only one file can be opened at a time), is there a strategy to simultaneously sort all of the arrays in-place so as to minimize the overall cost?

Note that the data is far too large for everything to be stored in memory, but there should be no problem storing `~10` entries from all arrays in memory `(i.e. 10x1M values).`

Comment: Are the arrays already sorted itself?

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: "The ith file contains the ith entry of all arrays." So file 1 contains the first item for each array? So if I wanted to create the first array, I'd take the first item from file 1, the first item from file 2, etc?

Comment: When you say, "number of files that I need to open," do you really mean, "number of times I have to open a file?"

Comment: Arrays are not pre-sorted.  Not a homework question (it's for computing exact percentiles of a large dataset at multiple grid points). It is correct that file i contains arr1[i], arr2[i], ..., arrN[i].  And yes, I mean "the number of times I have to open a file".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has lack of information. There is no mention if the arrays are already sorted itself or not. I am going to answer assuming the arrays are not sorted itself.

> The data is organized so that the ith file contains the ith entry of
>   all arrays.

From this, I can assume this -

```
file i
------------
arr1[i]
arr2[i]
arr3[i]
...
...
arrN[i] # N = ~1M
```

1. You mentioned the number of arrays are `1M` and number of files `1K`, so according this no array will contain more than `1K` elements otherwise more files would be required.
2. Each file contains `1M` elements.

> ....but there should be no problem storing ~10 entries from all arrays
>   in memory (i.e. 10x1M values).

So, we should be able to load all elements of a file in memory as it won't be more than `1M` elements.

So load each file in memory and sort the elements of the file.

Then apply [K-Way Merge Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-Way_Merge_Algorithms) using minheap to sort the `1K` files holding sorted elements. This step will take `c * 1M` elements to load in memory when `c` is small constant (`c < 3`).

Let me know if you have any trouble to understand K-way merging.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need -- specifically the external merge sort you describe (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting).  Thanks!